# How can different animations can be attached to an image dynamically in react-native?

Tags: react-native, animation

Asume there is an image on the screen and when a user presses another image (say right arrow) the first image goes right and when the user presses a third image (say left arrow) the first image goes left.

Briefly something like this, the left arrow should move the stickman to the left and the right should move to the right:

[image: Left and Right Arrows with Stickman]

According to the documentation, an image can have multiple animations (transforms, scales, opacity changes etc) but it seems all those animations  need to be run parallel (simultaneously).

My question is about doing this with a function call freely from unrelated objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have an animation value for how much you want to move the stick man. Just give the stick man a 
`style={{transform:[{translateX: this.stickManTranslateX}]}}` then you can just have the arrows use the moveStickManLeft function for it to move in different directions.

```
    stickManTranslateX = new Animated.value(0);

    moveStickManLeft = toValue => {
         this.stickManTranslateX.setValue(toValue);
    }
```

Comment: You are right with the question, it seems my question is not aiming the exact point. The purpose was to have “different styles”, for example an arrow for “translateX” and the arrow for “scale” would be a better example. Anyhow, your answer is OK for the way that I asked the question. Thanks..